# Operation is not supported while cat memory usage of docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, kubernetes

**Environment**

- Ubuntu 13.04
- Docker 1.7.0 (and 1.6.2)

**Problem**

After starting up kubernetes cluster, I find it's hard to get the minion resource info, so I cat `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.memsw.usage_in_bytes`, Ubuntu complains that "operation is not supported" even cat with sudo.

Docker did not support ubuntu raring right now, and I've installed Docker 1.6.2 and 1.7.0 from ppa, but neither of them works fine. What's the problem here, or is there some docker packages running on Ubuntu 13.04?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move to a supported (LTS) version.

If you look at the installation doc
https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/

you will find Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thanks! I will upgrade to 14.04, would you like to show me the reason that docker not support 13.04?

Comment: I guess docker supports only the LTS version of Ubuntu (12.04, 14.04, 16.04) and the most recent versions